# Create a textbox where the text always says MINUTES

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to have a textbox where the content says:

```
"3 minutes"
```

But when the person is writing on it, disappears the word minutes and when has lost the focus, again appears the word minutes.

Im developing in WPF

Comment: Im not good at WPF, may not be good solution also, but dont you have focus and click events in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking to remove the `unit` from the textbox `OnFocus` and append it when the focus is lost,

```
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox;
    if ((textbox = sender as TextBox) != null)
    {
        // Append the unit if any, otherwise the text remains unchanged
        if(textbox.Tag != null)
        {
            var unit = textbox.Tag.ToString();
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(unit) == false)
            {
                textbox.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} {1}", textbox.Text, unit);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox;
    if((textbox = sender as TextBox) != null)
    {
        // Note that this assumes values of the type '[value] [units]' (single space delimiter)
        var valueAndUnit = textbox.Text.Split(' ');

        // If there is a unit then store it to the Tag property
        if(valueAndUnit.Length > 1)
        {
            textbox.Tag = valueAndUnit[1];
        }

        textbox.Text = valueAndUnit[0];
    }
}
```

Also, take a look are [textbox Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/06/24/wpf-textbox-validation.aspx) and [TextChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged.aspx) to santise the text as the user inputs the values (for example, allow only digits to be entered when the value is an integer).

Answer (score 1):

A very cut and dry approach that will give you a start to make something better. This doesn't work at all if there isn't any way to lose focus from the textbox (ie. it is the only control on the window)

```
private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(" minutes", "");
}

private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " minutes";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in javascript with something like like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j8Jtu/).

I don't think there's a server side "Focus" event, and I have always thought handling the blur (TextChanged) event server side is bad. I don't want a form to post when my cursor leave a field.